# How do you search for questions filtered by a particular user?

Tags: support, search, users

I want to do a search on StackOverflow for a few terms, but also by user, since I know which user referenced the item I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `user` operator:

```
user:id a few other terms
```

where the *id* is a numeric ID (not username) or the keyword `me` (to indicate yourself)

See: 
[Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)

(it's one of the operators listed under "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options" )

Comment: It needs to be pointed out that *id* means *numeric id* as found in the URL of your user page. Users confused about this trying to use their alphanumeric login name will NOT get this information from this accepted answer.

Comment: ok that's great, but how do you find out someone's userid to begin with if all you know is their username or a substring of their name?

Comment: @Victor T.: you can search the users list; if multiple users match, you have your work cut out for you...