# How to search within the questions of a user?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you search by user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-do-you-search-by-user)

I'm trying to search within one of my questions, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to random's answer (in case it wasn't obvious), to search in *someone else's* answers, use their user ID:

> user:22656

Comment: this is now automatically prefixed to the search boxes on user pages, too

Answer (score 2):

Include this within the search box along with whatever terms/tags you're hunting:

> user:me